# Metaprogramming in Swift

Tags: swift, template-meta-programming, generics

Coming from C++, I'm trying to do some metaprogramming in Swift. For example, I'd like to implement a metafunction that adds two numbers. I've tried something like this:

```
protocol IntWrapper {
    class var value: Int { get }
}

struct A: IntWrapper {
    static let value = 5
}

struct B: IntWrapper {
    static let value = 7
}

struct Sum<T: IntWrapper, U: IntWrapper>: IntWrapper {
    static let value = T.value + U.value
}
```

This, however, doesn't work: Xcode complains that `T.Type` doesn't have a member `value` (or just crashes, sometimes.)

How can implement such functionality?

Comment: Hey sir´s .... Almost one year later... Do we have any news about Swift and Metaprogramming?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`static` stored properties are not (currently) supported on generic objects. When I put your code in a playground, I actually get this error:

```
Playground execution failed: <EXPR>:23:5: error: static variables not yet supported in generic types
    static let value = T.value + U.value
    ^~~~~~
```

You can get around that by using a computed property instead (which may have been what you wanted in the first place anyway):

```
struct Sum<T: IntWrapper, U: IntWrapper>: IntWrapper {
    static var value: Int {
        return T.value + U.value
    }
}
```

***Note:** Since it's a computed property, you need to declare `value` with `var` and not `let`.*

With those changes, `println(Sum<A, B>.value)` prints `12` like you'd expect.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really sure what I wanted (in the language semantics sense). The final goal is that once all optimizations are enabled, `Sum<A, B>.value` will be reduced to a constant in the resulting binary code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to match your definitions and implement the protocol differently. *(I'm not a swift developer, but I've been learning as I help people on stackoverflow.)*

```
protocol IntWrapper {
  static var value : Int { get }
}
struct A: IntWrapper {
  static var value : Int { get { 5 } }
}
```

You were calling for a `class var`, but then you defined a `static let`. Subtle difference, but I think it matters here.

Comment: Protocols cannot have static properties, the compiler throws an error message if you try.